# pygame in anaconda prompt

Tags: python, pygame, anaconda, conda

I am using tensorflow environment in Anaconda Prompt and I am trying to install pygame but I am getting the following error.

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found
to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your environment:

Specifications:

  - pygame -> python[version='2.7.*|3.5.*']

Your python: python=3.7

If python is on the left-most side of the chain, that's the version you've asked for.
When python appears to the right, that indicates that the thing on the left is somehow
not available for the python version you are constrained to. Note that conda will not
change your python version to a different minor version unless you explicitly specify
that.
```

How do I install pygame in this case. I am somewhat new to conda.

Comment: What do you understand from that error?

Answer (score 0):

If you skip conda and use `pip` as per [recommendation](https://www.pygame.org/wiki/GettingStarted), you probably get it working:

```
python3 -m pip install -U pygame
```

Comment: I am running a virtual environment on conda where i will require pygame. I have already installed it originally from pip. Should I be doing it here again?

Comment: The `-U` means update, you probably have an old installation.

Comment: @S_I2020 _I have already installed it originally from pip._ Can you expand on that?